# Como preencher dados de formulário próprio do tema do Wordpress utilizando jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou utilizando um tema que possui uma estrutura própria de formulário.
Preciso fazer com que esse `formulário` acesse dados da [API da tabela fipe](https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/carros/marcas) e preencha o campo de marca e modelo do carro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei inserir uma `<option>` dentro do `<select>` da marca, utilizando esse código:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var selectbox=$("#avia_4_1");
        selectbox.append($('<option>').text("test").val("test"));
    });
```

Porém o mesmo não funciona e o seguinte erro ocorre:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Esse código é adicionado através de um bloco de código do editor visual do tema. Preciso preencher o formulário mas não encontro uma maneira que funcione.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema com a execução do jQuery estava acontecendo por executar o código somente no modo de visualizar alterações do wordpress, o que estava gerando algum conflito.

O código que criei para alimentar o formulário foi esse:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var urlBase = "https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/carros/";

//Carrega as marcas
jQuery.getJSON( urlBase + "marcas", function( data ) {
    var htmlOptions = "<option value=\"\">Selecione</option>";
    jQuery.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        htmlOptions += "<option value=\"" + val.codigo + "\">" + val.nome + "</option>";
    });

    jQuery("#avia_4_1").html(htmlOptions);
});

jQuery("#avia_4_1").change(function(){
    jQuery.getJSON( urlBase + "marcas/" + jQuery(this).val() + "/modelos", function( data ) {
        var htmlOptions = "";
        jQuery.each( data.modelos, function( key, val) {
            htmlOptions += "<option value=\"" + val.codigo + "\">" + val.nome + "</option>";
        });

        jQuery("#avia_5_1").html(htmlOptions);
    });
});

jQuery("#avia_5_1").change(function(){
    jQuery.getJSON( urlBase + "marcas/" + jQuery("#avia_4_1").val() + "/modelos/" + jQuery(this).val() + "/anos", function( data ) {
        var htmlOptions = "";
        jQuery.each( data, function(  key, val ) {
            htmlOptions += "<option value=\"" + val.codigo + "\">" + val.nome + "</option>";
        });

        jQuery("#avia_6_1").html(htmlOptions);
    });             
});});
```

Assim consegui solucionar o problema para integrar esses dados com um formulário próprio do tema Enfold.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode montar a string com todas as `<option>` e depois fazer o append, deixando seu código assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selectbox = $("#avia_4_1");

    $.get(
        'https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/carros/marcas',
        function(api_array) {
            var options = '';
            $.each(api_array, function(i, obj) {
                options += '<option value="'+obj.codigo+'">'+obj.nome+'</option>';
            });
            selectbox.append(options);
        },
        "json"
    );
});
```

Fiz um fiddle para testar: https://jsfiddle.net/felipe_elia/upnqv4q8/

Comment: Fala Felipe, o meu problema está mais ligado na impressão do meu jQuery, que não estava funcionando.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Sim, respondi abaixo, valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var urlBase = "http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/";
    $("#marcas").hide();
    $("#veiculos").hide();
    $("#ano").hide();
    $("#tipo").change(function(){
        $("#marcas").hide();
        $("#veiculos").hide();
        $("#ano").hide();
        $.getJSON(urlBase + $("#tipo").val() + "/marcas" + ".json", function( data ){
            var items = ["<option value=\"\">ESCOLHA UMA MARCA</option>"];
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                items += ("<option value='" + val.id + "'>" + val.name + "</option>" );
            });
            $("#marcas").show();
            $("#marcas").html(items);
        });
    });
    $("#marcas").change(function(){
        $("#veiculos").hide();
        $("#ano").hide();
        $.getJSON(urlBase + $("#tipo").val() + "/veiculos/" + $(this).val() + ".json", function( data ){
            var items = ["<option value=\"\">ESCOLHA UM VEICULO</option>"];
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                items += ("<option value='" + val.id + "'>" + val.name + "</option>" );
            });
            $("#veiculos").show();
            $("#veiculos").html(items);
        });
    });
    $("#veiculos").change(function(){
        $("#ano").hide();
        $.getJSON(urlBase  + $("#tipo").val() + "/veiculo/" + $("#marcas").val() + "/" + $(this).val() + ".json", function( data){
            var items = ["<option value=\"\">ESCOLHA O ANO</option>"];
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                items += ("<option value='" + val.id + "'>" + val.name + "</option>" );
            });
            $("#ano").show();
            $("#ano").html(items);
        });
    });
    $(this).change(function(){
        $("#selecao").html("Marca: " + $("#marcas option:selected").text() + " Veiculo: " + $("#veiculos option:selected").text() + " Ano: " + $("#ano option:selected").text())
    });           
});
```

Fiz esse código com base no seu código anterior, mas como reparei que o link está fora do ar usei esse http://fipeapi.appspot.com/
Só que diferente do seu código, já inseri a escolha de carros, motos e caminhões assim não tendo a necessidade de criar um para cada tipo.

Espero que possa ajudar, pois seu código me ajudou muito a chegar a essa conclusão.

Também estão inseridos `.hide` e `.show` conforme selecionar o campo select, estou começando ainda com jQuery, não tenho muitas habilidades, mas fica aí para caso precisar.